# iPhone table scroll to

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

After my table view has loaded, I need  it to scroll to the 12th row.

How can I do this in the ViewDidAppear ?

(In MonoTouch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat: [Setting scroll position in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413055/setting-scroll-position-in-uitableview)