# How to change UITableView size when UIKeyboard is visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have an application with a UITableView that has UITextFields inside UITableViewCells which the user will have either the virtual UIKeyboard or a Bluetooth keyboard connected to enter text into the UITextFields.

If the Bluetooth keyboard is connected I would like to keep the UITableView full height when selecting and entering text. When there is no Bluetooth keyboard connected if its visible I would like to reduce the UITableview to fit with the UIkeyboard is showing, if its not showing then I would like to make the UITableView full size again.

I have tried to do this by using the UIKeyboard delegate methods

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
```

For some reason keyboardDidShow is not accessed ever but keyboardDidHide is accessed when the UIKeyboard is removed from view and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    self.tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 255); // or -216
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    self.tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And in `UITextField` Delegate Methods

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{   
    CGRect rc = [textField bounds];
    rc = [textField convertRect:rc toView:self.tblView];
    CGPoint pt = rc.origin;
    pt.x = 0;
    if(rc.origin.y > 200)
        pt.y -=  150;
    else
        pt.y -= rc.origin.y;
    [self.tblView setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: okay so this works in respect to the view scrolling on enter, however the keyboardDidShow method still dose not get used... i cannot tell why. I put a breakpoint in there and it is never hit.

Comment: whoops needed to add the observer **[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
**

Answer (score 0):

use optimized way like this

**selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:**

Selects a row in the receiver identified by index path, optionally scrolling the row to a location in the receiver.

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

Special Considerations
Passing UITableViewScrollPositionNone will result in no scrolling, rather than the minimum scrolling described for that constant. To scroll to the newly selected row with minimum scrolling, select the row using this method with UITableViewScrollPositionNone, then call scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: with UITableViewScrollPositionNone.

```
NSIndexPath *rowToSelect;  // assume this exists and is set properly
UITableView *myTableView;  // assume this exists

[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

more understand [Setting scroll position in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413055/setting-scroll-position-in-uitableview)