# Scroll above UITableView to activate pullToRefresh

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` with pull to refresh added to it, I want when my `viewDidAppear` executes it scrolls above my cells to activate pull to refresh action.

Comment: You want? That's great, do it.

Comment: That's not an answer!!!

Comment: And "here's my homework, how do I do it?" is not a valid Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not scroll your cells but you should directly call the refresh method when `viewDidAppear` gets called. The action which you are taking at the time of pull to refresh, you can directly fire at the time of `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score -1):

Apurv is probably right that you should refresh your tableView programmatically.

Anyway, if you want to scroll tableView somewhere, you can do it with:

> [self tableView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:

more info/credit: [Setting scroll position in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413055/setting-scroll-position-in-uitableview)

Comment: I want to scroll above all cells